# How do I read the header or footer of a Word document with docx4js?

Tags: javascript, docx4js

I can read the contents of the file with

```
docx4js.load(fileName)).then(docx => {
    console.log("Content of the body is: " + docx.officeDocument.content.text());
});
```

But how do I print out the text in the header?

Comment: @RobG Ha!  I beat you to it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379023/create-new-tag-called-docx4js

Comment: @RobG It's there.  I can see it in encased in convoluted XML in the debugger.  I just can't figure out how to get it out.

Comment: Cool, there's now a docx4js tag. :-) I guess page header is different to document header?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually.  Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docx, there is only 1 header and 1 footer. You cant have a footer in 1st page that is unlike footer in 2nd page and same goes with header. Once you change the header in any of the pages, all headers on other pages change. So getting the 1st header or footer is like getting them for all pages.

To get header you do it like

`docx.getObjectPart("word/header1.xml").text();`

And you can do the same thing for the footer

`docx.getObjectPart("word/footer1.xml").text();`

you can get the content/body as well doing like

`docx.getObjectPart("word/document.xml").text();`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to get me the header text from the first page, at least:

```
docx.getObjectPart("word/header1.xml").text()
```